# Pointer vs Pointer to Structure Bug

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

Here are both of My Codes. One Using structure and Another Using Pointer to Structure. But when I am not using a Pointer it's not working. Al though I think they are same. But I am still a beginner. So I need to understand what's going wrong.

Not Working Code:

```
struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

void insert(struct Node** head_ref,int data){
    //Not Working Here. The Header should change after every insert but it isn't Moving from it's Memory;

    struct Node temp ;

    temp.data = data;
    temp.next = (*head_ref);
    (*head_ref) = &temp;
}

int main(){
    struct Node *head = NULL;

    insert(&head,4);
    insert(&head,2);
    insert(&head,11);
    insert(&head,9);

            while(head->next !=0 ){
                std::cout << head->data <<" ";
                head = head->next;
            }
    return 0;
}
```

Working Code:

```
struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

void insert(struct Node** head_ref,int data){
    //The Problem is in This Line. Pointer to Structure is Working But only Structure isn't
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node)) ;

    temp->data = data;

    temp->next = (*head_ref);
    (*head_ref) = temp;
}

int main(){
    struct Node *head = NULL;

    insert(&head,4);
    insert(&head,2);
    insert(&head,11);
    insert(&head,9);

            while(head->next !=0 ){
                std::cout << head->data <<" ";
                head = head->next;
            }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to highlight the exact difference between the two. It takes a while to find.

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in C++. `new` is almost always what you need. `unique_ptr<Node>` is even better. If you're not doing this for educational purposes, don't write your own container implementations; you're never going to match the std library's quality. `insert` should have been `Node::insert` instead. If you're not going to use `unique_ptr<Node>` then you have to manually clean-up after every dynamic allocation you make.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq -- why have you deleted substantial portions of OP code, without comment? Now there is nothing close to a [MCVE], and the posted code looks like it could be C, instead of C++. The original code was clearly C++ despite OP tags. Rolling back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the code `struct Node temp ; ... (*head_ref) = &temp;`, you store the address of a local variable. As soon as function `insert` has finished, the lifetime of the object stored in this variable ends, and accessing the pointer after this time is undefined behaviour.

This is different from your second case, where `struct Node* temp = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node))` allocates an object dynamically; the lifetime of such an object ends when it is deleted explicitly, such that you may then refer to its address.

Comment: Thanks, I got the Concept Now. Solved my Problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is the difference between the heap and stack [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)

```
void insert(struct Node** head_ref,int data){
    //Not Working Here. The Header should change after every insert but it isn't Moving from it's Memory;

    struct Node temp ;

    temp.data = data;
    temp.next = (*head_ref);
    (*head_ref) = &temp;
}
```

In the original code, temp is located on `stack`, since got destroyed automatically at the end of the scope

```
void insert(struct Node** head_ref,int data){
    //The Problem is in This Line. Pointer to Structure is Working But only Structure isn't
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node)) ;

    temp->data = data;

    temp->next = (*head_ref);
    (*head_ref) = temp;
}
```

This could work because it is located on `heap`, thus you have to manually delete it when you finish using it